# Antimalware Service Executable uses High CPU and blocks running IIS .Net Core App

Tags: .net, api, iis, windows-defender, antimalware

I have a .Net Core API on Windows server 2019 VPS, its been two days now as and when request comes to API 'Antimalware Service Executable' kicks in to scan the app, this leads to high CPU use as well as API is not able to respond to any request, every request gets failed until the scan is over and the scan takes hours to finish.

have tried re-deploying the app after emptying the directory and still the issue exists.
There are other small console apps that exist on the same server has no issue at all.
can anyone help me with what could be wrong here that suddenly changed the behavior of the Antimalware?

[image: Task Manager]

**Update :**
This issue is not specific to .Net Core but i have deployed .Net Framework API on the same server for testing and as soon sends a request to the new API Antimalware kicks in and IIS Worker Process takes about 34% CPU and 66% by Antimalware , this seems not specific to API instead related to IIS process , has anyone had similar situation with Windows Defender on Win Server 2019 ?
Further i have scanned entire server with 'Microsoft Safety Scanner' and found 0 infected file
also tried SFC /Scannow have completed without finding any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the issue has been resolved by restoring Firewalls settings to default.
not sure what magic was but did a restore and Antimalware CPU usage has reduced to 3% and that is also occasionally. yes, obviously I had to do all the required firewall custom settings once again, I did not export and import the policy as that might bring those wrong config again in.

[image]